# How to rotate triangle around center?

Tags: java, android, math, geometry

I am drawing a triangle on canvas:

```
float x = 540;
float y = 960;
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(x, y);
path.lineTo(x+18, y+60);
path.lineTo(x-18, y+60);
path.lineTo(x, y);
canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

This canvas has another objects. But I need to rotate only this triangle around center of this triangle on a random angle (between 0 and 360). How to implement it? How to get coordinates vertexes of a triangle after rotation?

Comment: So is this a programming or a math question? I's say the second, so here's a hint: google for "rotation matrix".

Comment: belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/ (this option doesn't exist on the "This question belongs on another site in Stack Exchange network")

Answer (score 2):

Its simple math, if the center of the triangle is (x,y) and the center-vertex distace is A, the three vertex will be

-(A*Math.cos(angle),A*Math.sin(angle))

-(A*Math.cos(angle+2*Math.PI/3),A*Math.sin(angle+2*Math.PI/3))

-(A*Math.cos(angle-2*Math.PI/3),A*Math.sin(angle-2*Math.PI/3))

Comment: Do you mean that?

 x1=(float) (x1-l1*Math.cos(angle));
         y1=(float) (y1-l1*Math.sin(angle));
         
         x2=(float) (x2-l2*Math.cos(angle+2*Math.PI/3));
         y2=(float) (y2-l2*Math.sin(angle+2*Math.PI/3));
         
         x3=(float) (x3-l3*Math.cos(angle-2*Math.PI/3));
         y3=(float) (y3-l3*Math.sin(angle-2*Math.PI/3));

If yes, that is doesn't work.

Comment: that doesn't seem particularly simple to me.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by this way:

```
float angle = (float) Math.toRadians(90); // Angle to rotate

// Size of triangle
final float height = 60;
final float width = 36;

// Display coordinates where triangle will be drawn
float centerX = 540;
float centerY = 960;

// Vertex's coordinates before rotating
float x1 = centerX;
float y1 = centerY - height / 2;
float x2 = centerX + width / 2;
float y2 = centerY + height / 2;
float x3 = centerX - width / 2;
float y3 = y2;

// Rotating
float x1r = (float) ((x1 - centerX) * Math.cos(angle) - (y1 - centerY) * Math.sin(angle) + centerX);
float y1r = (float) ((x1 - centerX) * Math.sin(angle) + (y1 - centerY) * Math.cos(angle) + centerY);

float x2r = (float) ((x2 - centerX) * Math.cos(angle) - (y2 - centerY) * Math.sin(angle) + centerX);
float y2r = (float) ((x2 - centerX) * Math.sin(angle) + (y2 - centerY) * Math.cos(angle) + centerY);

float x3r = (float) ((x3 - centerX) * Math.cos(angle) - (y3 - centerY) * Math.sin(angle) + centerX);
float y3r = (float) ((x3 - centerX) * Math.sin(angle) + (y3 - centerY) * Math.cos(angle) + centerY);

// Drawing
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(x1r, y1r);
path.lineTo(x2r, y2r);
path.lineTo(x3r, y3r);
path.lineTo(x1r, y1r);
canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

Thanks to Gimka and Nofate for help.